# How to force iOS camera to take a picture programmatically using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-camera

I need the iOS camera to take a picture without any input from the user. How would I go about doing this? This is my code so far:

```
-(void)initCapture{
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *newVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] init];

    AVCaptureStillImageOutput *newStillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                nil];


    [newStillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];


    AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    if ([newCaptureSession canAddInput:newVideoInput]) {
        [newCaptureSession addInput:newVideoInput];
    }
    if ([newCaptureSession canAddOutput:newStillImageOutput]) {
        [newCaptureSession addOutput:newStillImageOutput];
    }
    self.stillImageOutput = newStillImageOutput;
}
```

What else do I need to add and where do I go from here? I don't want to take a video, only a single still image. Also, how would I convert the image into a UIImage afterwards? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Look at AVCaptureSession on how to take take picture without user input. You will need to add AVCaptureDevice for camera to the session.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an AVCaptureStillImageOutput, `stillImageOutput`. Plus you need to have stored your capture session where you can get at it later. Call it `self.sess`. Then:

```
AVCaptureConnection *vc = 
    [self.stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[self.sess startRunning];
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:vc
                                          completionHandler:
 ^(CMSampleBufferRef buf, NSError *err) {
     NSData* data = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:buf];
     UIImage* im = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:someframe];
         iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
         iv.image = im;
         [self.view addSubview: iv];
         [self.iv removeFromSuperview]; // in case we already did this
         self.iv = iv;
         [self.sess stopRunning];
     });
 }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can you explain what all of this code does line by line please?

Answer (score 0):

As @Salil says, the apple's official AVFoundation is very useful, take a look at that to understand main concept. Then you can download a sample code to see how to achieve the goal.

[Here is the sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) to take still images with a preview layer.